# Unable to access Steam due to port blocks

Tags: router, vpn, ip, tunnel

I am on a restricted network. There are a set of LAN IP addresses which have full access of internet service and there are some another set of LAN IP addresses which have some ports blocked (specifically UDP which is used by Steam). There is a common gateway which gives each internal LAN IP the public IP to access the WAN. i wish to access the full internet while accessing through the restricted IP address.
I don't want the solution to be using some commercial VPN service.

The solution which came to my mind- Being both kinds of IP address on the same LAN, if I can set up a tunnel to redirect requests from restricted ones to unrestricted ones, I may be able to solve this problem. I do have usage access to both kinds of routers.

I don't know how to solve such a thing. Kindly help.

Comment: Why does the network administrator block those ports?

Comment: I don't know the answer. However, if you are trying to bypass your employer's network restrictions in order to play games at work, you risk losing your job.

Comment: I’m surprised this questions still open but it’s off-topic here for 2 reasons, it’s about a corporate IT network and it’s about defeating network security.